# How can I change my existing column in MariaDB to Not Null?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, notnull

> Message    : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near ''country_of_residence_id' INTEGER NOT NULL' Statement  :
>   ALTER TABLE address ALTER COLUMN 'country_of_residence_id' INTEGER NOT
>   NULL

In my table 'address' I want to set an already existing column 'country_of_residence_id' to NOT NULL.

I tried it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE address
ALTER COLUMN 'country_of_residence_id' INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

My IDE underlines INTEGER and says: DROP or SET expected, got "INTEGER"

When I add SET before INTEGER it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 9):

I found it here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/

```
alter table address modify country_of_residence_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make all existing `NULL` values of rows disappear:

```
UPDATE [Table_Name] SET [Column_Name]=0 WHERE [Column_Name] IS NULL;
```

Then, update(alter) the table definition to reject `NULL`s:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table_Name] MODIFY [Column_Name] BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The update null values line is key if you already have values in table, otherwise nothing changes and you get something like: `ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'confirmed' at row 1`
 I think this should be accepted answer for this reason.